# Post install boot gets /dev/disk/by-uuid/... does no exist

Tags: boot

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS on an older (2005 BIOS date) Win machine. I've wiped out the old partitions and installed this fresh. Running the "Try Ubuntu" works fine (I'm using it right now.) The installation seems to go fine (I've done it twice now). But when I reboot the system to Ubuntu I get an error message:

"Gave up waiting for root device. ..."
Eventually I get this line:

"ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/234...89d72 does not exist." (the ... is the whole UUID which I will not utter here.)

I've installed Ubuntu several times on various laptops and never had a problem. Any ideas as to what this might be would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what this was. The there was a "large" drive on the system that the Windows OS had "lost track of" - i.e. couldn't access - but Windows still booted fine - i.e. it wasn't the boot device.

However, Ubuntu seemed to recognize that the device was there and just insisted that it if couldn't talk to it then it wasn't going to boot.

So the answer was to simply unplug the SATA cable that connected it to the motherboard and, hey presto! Ubuntu couldn't see the drive at all and seems to boot just fine.

If I was calling the shots I'd call this a bug - at least it is unexpected behavior. Flag an error in big letters? Fine. Fail to boot? Not cool.